# Why is the raw url of pdf file in github can't be open with browser directly instead of download

Tags: github, github-pages

I tried pdf, txt and png file url, only pdf url can't be open with browser if click the url, but trigger download.

I google this but only got how to fix, like instead with google doc or use pdf.js, or other html code.

What is the reason? the website ? Forgive me that i have no idea of website architecture.

Answer (score 0):

When you get a file from a website, it has a content type sent along with it.  Depending on the content type, the browser may choose to display it.  For example, content type "application/pdf" might be shown in a browser, but "application/octet-stream" will be downloaded.

The raw URL on GitHub has content type "application/octet-stream" (a binary file) so that it will be downloaded.

The only way around this, since you can't change GitHub's code that sets the content type, is to get the data from JavaScript and parse it there -- by using pdf.js or something similar.